# Как сгенерировать множественное поле в админке Symfony

Tags: php, symfony2

Приветствую всех. 
Мне поручили модернизировать существующий сайт, который написан на Symfony 2. Сейчас имеется список новостей, к ним нужно добавить галерею.
Я создала таблицу "news_gallery":

- id   integer NOT NULL [pk]
- title    character varying(255)
- image    character varying(255)  NOT NULL
- id_news  integer [fk]

Создала класс NewsGallerys:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_gallery")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\NewsGallerysRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class NewsGallerys
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=1024)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize="2m",
     *     mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg"}
     * )    
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="newsgallery", fileNameProperty="image")
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;
    }

    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News", inversedBy="news_gallerys")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_news", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    public $news;

    /**
     * Set news
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\News $news
     *
     * @return news_gallerys
     */
    public function setIdNews(\AppBundle\Entity\News $news)
    {
        $this->news = $news;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get news
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\News
     */
    public function getIdNews()
    {
        return $this->news;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }
}
```

В классе News добавила связь:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
    use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

    /**
     * News
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="news")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\NewsRepository")
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
     * @Vich\Uploadable
     */
    class News
    {
    /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NewsGallerys", mappedBy="news")
         */
        private $news_gallerys;

        /**
         * Add news_gallerys
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\NewsGallerys $news_gallerys
         *
         * @return News
         */
        public function addNewsGallery(\AppBundle\Entity\NewsGallerys $news_gallerys)
        {
            $this->news_gallerys[] = $news_gallerys;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove news_gallerys
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\NewsGallerys $news_gallerys
         */
        public function removeNewsGallery(\AppBundle\Entity\NewsGallerys $news_gallerys)
        {
            $this->news_gallerys->removeElement($news_gallerys);
        }

        /**
         * Get news_gallerys
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        public function getNewsGallery()
        {
            return $this->news_gallerys;
        }
    ....
    }
```

В публичную часть сайта в шаблон эту галерею вывела. А вот как сгенерировать это поле в форму добавления новостей через админку, понятия не имею. Перечитала кучу документации и кучу форумов, но ничего найти не могу.

Вот часть файла config.yml для Новостей и самой галереии:

```
News:
  label: app.menu.news
  class: AppBundle\Entity\News
  list:
      fields:
          - name
          - shortDescription
  show:
      fields:
          - name
          - shortDescription
          - fullDescription
  form:
      fields:
          - { property: 'created' }
          - name
          - shortDescription
          - fullDescription
NewsGallerys:
  label: app.menu.news_gallery
  class: AppBundle\Entity\NewsGallerys
  list:
      fields:
          - title
          - { property: 'image', type: 'image', base_path: %app.path.newsgallery% }
  show:
      fields:
          - title
          - { property: 'image', type: 'image', base_path: %app.path.newsgallery% }
  form:
      fields:
          - title
          - { property: 'imageFile', type: 'vich_image' }
```

Как в News добавить свойство "news_gallerys" чтобы можно было загружать фото бесконечно много?

Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 2):

Решение нашлось благодаря [вот этому парню](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/825#issuecomment-212579578). Он штатно использовал тип "collection"

Вот что у меня получается в итоге:
файл News.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * News
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="news")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\NewsRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class News
{

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @return datetime
     */
    public function getCreated() {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function setCreated($newdate) {
    $this->created = $newdate;
    return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable = true)
     */
    protected $updated;


    /**
     * Gets triggered only on insert

     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function onPrePersist()
    {
        $this->created = new \DateTime("now");
    }

    /**
     * Gets triggered every time on update

     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function onPreUpdate()
    {
        $this->updated = new \DateTime("now");
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="shortDescription", type="string", length=1024)
     */
    private $shortDescription;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fullDescription", type="text")
     */
    private $fullDescription;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return News
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set shortDescription
     *
     * @param string $shortDescription
     * @return News
     */
    public function setShortDescription($shortDescription)
    {
        $this->shortDescription = $shortDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shortDescription
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getShortDescription()
    {
        return $this->shortDescription;
    }


    /**
     * Set fullDescription
     *
     * @param string $fullDescription
     * @return News
     */
    public function setFullDescription($fullDescription)
    {
        $this->fullDescription = $fullDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fullDescription
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFullDescription()
    {
        return $this->fullDescription;
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=1024)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="newsgallery", fileNameProperty="image")
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;
    }

    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NewsGallerys", mappedBy="news")
     */
    private $news_gallerys;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->news_gallerys = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->name;
    }
    /**
     * Add news_gallerys
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\NewsGallerys $news_gallerys
     *
     * @return News
     */
    public function addNewsGallerys(\AppBundle\Entity\NewsGallerys $news_gallerys)
    {
        $this->news_gallerys[] = $news_gallerys;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove news_gallerys
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\NewsGallerys $news_gallerys
     */
    public function removeNewsGallerys(\AppBundle\Entity\NewsGallerys $news_gallerys)
    {
        $this->news_gallerys->removeElement($news_gallerys);
    }

    /**
     * Get news_gallerys
     *
     * @return NewsGallerys[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getNewsGallerys()
    {
        return $this->news_gallerys;
    }
}
```

Файл NewsGallerys.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_gallery")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\NewsGallerysRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class NewsGallerys
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=1024)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize="2m",
     *     mimeTypes={"image/png", "image/jpeg"}
     * )    
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="newsgallery", fileNameProperty="image")
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return NewsGallerys
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->title = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param File|null $image
     * @return NewsGallerys
     */
    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }
    /**
     * @param string $image
     * @return NewsGallerys
     */
     public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News",cascade={"persist", "remove"},inversedBy="news_gallerys")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_news",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
     */
    public $news;
    public function __toString(){
        return (string) $this->name;
    }
}
```

в config.yml для сущности News прописала такие поля:

```
News:
  label: app.menu.news
  class: AppBundle\Entity\News
  list:
      fields:
          - name
          - shortDescription
  show:
      fields:
          - name
          - shortDescription
          - fullDescription
          - { property: 'image', type: 'image', base_path: %app.path.newsgallery% }
  form:
      fields:
          - { property: 'created' }
          - name
          - shortDescription
          - fullDescription
          - { property: 'imageFile', type: 'vich_image' }
          - { property: 'news_gallerys', type: 'collection', type_options: { entry_type: 'AppBundle\Form\ImageType' } }
```

Далее создала файл ImageType.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;

class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('imageFile', VichFileType::class)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\NewsGallerys'
        ));
    }
}
```

В итоге получаю множественное добавление файлов с типом картинки, если они уже добавлены в базе, отображается корректно, а вот добавить новую или удалить уже не могу. Выводит ошибку:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: "A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\News#news_gallerys' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: . To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"})."

Если кто подскажет как её решить, буду благодарна.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение _полностью_ Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Пока не могу полное готовое решение выложить, решился вопрос только с отображением полей в админке. Пока решаю вопрос с ошибкой при сохранении новости: request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException: "A new entity was found through the relationship 'AppBundle\Entity\News#news_gallerys' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: . To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"})."

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте!

Вот линк - там описан как раз ваш случай: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

Если вкратце:

- нужно в поле news_gallerys добавить опцию allow_add = true, и при
  необходимости - allow_delete = true
- после чего вывести в шаблон формы добавления изображений прототип:

  data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"
- и прикрутить js для добавления элементов формы

Comment: Приветствую, спасибо за ответ. Я не совсем опытный программист в сфере Symfony, поэтому не понимаю как мне этот использовать. Я работаю с формой в админке, а именно EasyAdmin. Т.е. Мне нужно чтобы при добавлении или редактировании "новости" добавлялись и удалялись фото для галереи новости, каскадом.

Comment: Смотри, у тебя в конфагах описана форма для News, в которую ты добавила поле news_gallerys. Нужно в type_options добавить 2 параметра - allow_add: true, allow_delete: true. Таким образом Symfony поймет что можно через форму News добавлять и удалять Объекты сущности NewsGallerys. Далее, в шаблоне формы, для div(или table, зависит от того как ты отображаешь галлерею новости) добавить атрибут data-prototype. Этот атрибут будет хранить html прототип ImageType(это как бы форма без данных, только html). Далее тебе нужно прикрутить js код для добавления/удаления элементов списка